Can YAML anchors include all keys after the anchor definition?
I would like to define the anchor to include all keys after the anchor definition.
I have these workarounds working:
Repeating the Over Arching Keyword:
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TriggerTemplate
spec:
  resourcetemplates:
    - apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
      kind: PipelineRun
      spec:
        workspaces:
          - name: source-code-1
            volumeClaimTemplate: &volume_claim_template_configurations
              spec:
                resources:
                  requests:
                    storage: 5Gi
          - name: source-code-2
            volumeClaimTemplate: *volume_claim_template_configurations

Overriding Nested Keywords:
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TriggerTemplate
spec:
  resourcetemplates:
    - apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
      kind: PipelineRun
      spec:
        workspaces:
          - &volume_claim_template
            name: source-code-1
            volumeClaimTemplate:
              spec:
                accessModes:
                  - ReadWriteOnce
                resources:
                  requests:
                    storage: 2Gi
                storageClassName: block
          - &volume_claim_template
            name: source-code-2

Instead, I'd like to do something like the following where the name key is not included in the anchor:
Include All Keys After Anchor Definition:
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TriggerTemplate
spec:
  resourcetemplates:
    - apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
      kind: PipelineRun
      spec:
        workspaces:
          - name: source-code-1
            &volume_claim_template
            volumeClaimTemplate:
              spec:
                accessModes:
                  - ReadWriteOnce
                resources:
                  requests:
                    storage: 2Gi
                storageClassName: block
          - name: source-code-2
            *volume_claim_template

Would I be able to do something like that in YAML?
Thank you for your time and help 
